# MediaWiki – Search for URL without results

Tags: php, search, mediawiki, wikipedia

I have a MediaWiki site where I have a domain name as headline. For example: *www.mydomain.org* defined as Headline 2 – not linked with the domain. Just Plain text as H2.

But when I try to search for `*mydo*` it does not output any result(s). When I remove the **www.** and the **.org** it gets found.

How can I solve the problem?
The search functionality in MediaWiki is not pretty good in my opinion so far...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like more of a support question for the maintainers of MediaWiki than anything about programming it. Perhaps some of the resources linked from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Help or more specifically https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication can help you find the right venue.

Comment: There is https://discourse-mediawiki.wmflabs.org/ which might be a good place for this question.